# Problem with ImageView onClickListener on Android

Tags: android

I have  problem, in my Android app, I have `ImageView` and I implemented `onClick` event but when I click on `ImageView` it looks like that it doesn't run `onClickListener` at all.

Any help?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: It doesn't looks like it should be, I have no choice.

Comment: <TableRow
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#AA0000AA">
  
    
    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imvSearchNear"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#AA0000AA"
      android:src="@drawable/search_vicinity"/>
    
   </TableRow>  //Problem is when I put property background ImageButton doesn't enter in clicklistener (I don't know why, without is ok but then look isn'ok)

Comment: I'm trying to make something similar dropdown list in ASP.NET, couple them on screen, I need to hide and show some TableRows on click.Maybe this up is totally wrong. Any new idea ?